# String error on Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem() query

Tags: sitecore-query

I am trying to run a fast query, however it is throwing an error after upgrading from 7.2 to 10.1 on `SelectSingleItem()`.

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectSingleItem("fast:/sitecore/content/#LJMU Website#/home/#about us#/news/features//#its international archaeology day#");
```

The exception is:

> System.ArgumentException
> HResult=0x80070057
> Message=String cannot
> be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue

Has anybody encountered this?

Comment: Fast:// Query is not supported in Sitecore 10.1 and onwards.

Comment: Cheers @MarekMusielak obviously that's the issue, what is new method?

Comment: Try without `fast:`